# Mapping variable names between frontend & backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm developing a full-stack application (React, Node, Postgres). When receiving the form data from the frontend, I expect certain variable names sush as `firstName` and I map `firstName` to `first_name` on the backend server to insert it into the postgres db. Now my question is regarding the GET requests and sending the data back to the front end:
Should I map the names back to the frontend naming convention on the server before I send the json (map `first_name` back to `firstName`) or handle the mapping on the frontend?
What is the best practice regarding such situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the best practice is to keep the code for the mapping in a single place: either in the backend, or in the frontend, not both. Keep the naming convention within each API consistent.

If your backend accepts `firstName` as input and does the mapping internally when inserting in the database, it should also do the mapping internally when reading from the database and provide `firstName` as output.

Answer (score -1):

In your SQL queries you can get the data renamed:

```
SELECT first_name as "firstName"
```

The object returned from the query will have the properties named correctly.

Comment: it does not sound like a good practice at all to handle that at database layer.

Comment: …actually it's `as "firstName"` in postgres. Without the quotes it would canonicalise the field name to lowercase.

Comment: Edited, thanks Bergi.

Comment: The most efficient solution, based on the circumstances, could be on the frontend side Aslan. But I'm not a big fan of it.

Comment: The UI should not have any knowledge about the underlying database structure of the data it is fetching or saving, and vice versa the database should not need to know anything about how it's being used by the UI. The interface (REST API, GraphQL, whatever) in the backend should be responsible for doing any conversions from both the request and response side of things. Separate those concerns. It may be slightly less efficient than the DB layer doing it, but it's worth it for long-term maintainability.